# How to extract TLS pre-master secret in .NET?

Tags: ssl, .net-core, wireshark

I am debugging a TLS HTTP/2 connection, and want to inspect the traffic for a simple .NET Core application in Wireshark, but without the TLS pre-master secret I'm unable to view the HTTP/2-messages.

If you got the pre-master secret in the NSS Key Log Format, it can be provided to Wireshark in *Edit → Preferences → Protocols → TLS → (Pre)-Master-Secret log filename*, and TLS traffic will be decrypted.

In curl this is done by setting the env `SSLKEYLOGFILE` to some file, e.g. `SSLKEYLOGFILE=/tmp/key curl https://www.google.com`, in Node you can add a param `node --tls-keylog=/tmp/key myapp.js` and in Java you can use the agent [extract-tls-secrets](https://github.com/neykov/extract-tls-secrets), but how to do it in .NET Core?

Ideally it would be something like `dotnet run --tls-keylog=/tmp/key` or that the env `SSLKEYLOGFILE` is used.

Comment: If you install *Fiddler* or any other debugging proxy that supports HTTP/2 you'll be able to inspect the requests the same way you don in eg Chrome's Network tab. Check [How To Enable HTTP/2 Traffic Capture Inside Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-enable-http-2-traffic-capture-inside-fiddler-everywhere)